# Conditionally exclude some resources in maven from war

Tags: java, maven

I developed an application, and its final war was OK in a development mode but it contains some configuration files which I need to externalize for production. I was able to manually alter the war and remove those files from it, but I want to automate this process. And I would like to keep the configuration files in the war for the development mode.

I read several questions on SO but they miss conditionality. The same applies to [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) where include/exclude cannot work under certain conditions (according to their samples). Using filters won't work, as I do not want to alter the content of copied files but skip them.

Sources:

```
src
  main
    resources
      some.properties
      server-keystore.jks
      signature.properties
      MyRequests.xsd
```

Development war:

```
WEB-INF
  classes
      some.properties
      server-keystore.jks
      signature.properties
      MyRequests.xsd
```

Production war:

```
WEB-INF
  classes
      signature.properties
      MyRequests.xsd
```

What is the proper way to achieve this effect? Thanks

Comment: See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html.

Comment: This may be the way, I used profile once to set the filter. This linked document says that profiles can be used to alter plugins and other POM parts. But I miss HOW section. I am maven newbie. Shall I in //profiles/profile specify maven-war-plugin configuration?

Comment: Yes. You can configure plugins in profile section.

Comment: Can you comment @blackbuild answer?

Comment: You can always put additional classifier to final name in order to indicate it is a `dev` artifact or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, I created two profiles, the production having //profiles/profile/build/resources/resource/excludes and it works like charm. Though I am confused if it is the proper way like @blackbuild noted.

Comment: The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name just after the version number.

Comment: I googled for classifiers and I found references only below plugin element of maven-jar-plugin. So I blindly edited my POM with: /project/profiles/profile[1]/build/plugins/plugin/configuration/classifier and rebuild the project. Is it correct? I do not see any change in the war (under META-INF).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I end up with the following solution. It does not use profiles, which are considered as antipattern by some guys: [blackbuild](http://www.blackbuild.com/how-to-really-use-maven-profiles-without-endangering-your-karma/) and [Henrik Larne](http://www.jayway.com/2010/01/21/one-artifact-with-multiple-configurations-in-maven/). The solution is built with classifiers and [maven war resources exclusion](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html). It will produce two wars that differ with their content and file name.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>dev</classifier>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-dev</webappDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>package-prod</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>prod</classifier>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-prod</webappDirectory>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/*.jks,WEB-INF/classes/some.properties</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score -4):

Please DON'T use profiles for this. The problem with profiles is that the resulting artifact contains no information about the profiles used to build it.

Basic rule: A profile must not change the result of the build.

Or the other way around: If you build the same source code revision, the result must be identical, regardless of profiles or arguments.

(see [How to really use Maven profiles (without endangering your karma)](http://www.blackbuild.com/how-to-really-use-maven-profiles-without-endangering-your-karma/) for more information)

So, a better way to do it would be to create two war modules, say `my-project` and `my-project-dev.war`.

If `my-project-dev.war` has a war-dependency on `my-project.war`, it will use your production war as overlay, resulting in a combined war files using your production and your development time resources.

Added bonus feature: in your development war, you can override entries of your production war (say, logging-config).

Comment: I upvoted your question for interesting information though I do not like proposed solution of having two projects.

Comment: The article is not consistent: "Let’s say that again: Regardless of the active profiles, the resulting (main) artifact of the build must be identical!" and "It is perfectly legal to have profiles skip or include additional artifacts according to build profiles." or I did not get it.

Comment: I fail to understand the statement `A profile must not change the result of the build` . My question is Why Not ? @blackbuild

Comment: @LeosLiterak The important part is that the artifacts must be the same. It is legal to create addtional artifacts or none at all. But if an artifact is created, it must be identical regardless of the used profile.

Comment: @SaifAsif Because maven (as every other build) should follow a simple basic principle: The same source code must result in the same artifact(s) - this is the foundation of repeatable builds. If this weren't true, you could not recreate old version without addtional knowhow. This would also invalidate the use of repository managers, because they operate by this contract.

Comment: @blackbuild I still don't agree with your statement `it must be identical regardless of the used profile`. I have used maven profiles for quite some time, and most of the time it was to manage building artifacts for different environments, and yes, the different profiles did result in different artificat being created. How-ever, I am not going to turn a deaf ear to your statements. Can you back your claims with some supporting links and/or documents?

Comment: @SaifAsif The only document I could provide which does state this is the one I linked above (which of course is biased, because I wrote it myself some years ago). I am working (and giving courses) in buildmanagent/maven for many years now. The problem with different target environments using profiles is that you cannot differentiate whether a given artifact was build for prod or test. In other words: the coordinates are the same, but the artifacts are different. Consider a release: Which profile gets deployes to your nexus?

Comment: If I am not careful, it can be any profile and thus resulting in the wrong artificat being deployed as a release. But if all the team members are well aware as to which profile will create what, then we can narrow down the chances of incorrect artifact deployment. Also, if you use nexus, you can define something similar to regex that actually deploys your artifact if it resembles a certain pattern. E.g I can define regex for `XXX-prod.war` as my production regex. So any war that is being generated by the production profile will contain prod in its final name and thus get uploaded

Comment: @SaifAsif One more remark (we should consider moving this discussion into a chatroom or a different question): If you only did your profiles on artifacts that never get deployed to nexus, you could stay safe. Still, you would have to take extreme care to prevent accidentially deploying a prod artifact to test or vice versa (potentially overiding your prod db with test data -> worst case scenario). Just stay on the safe side: give your different target environments different coordinates (classifer or artifactId), or IMHO even better, try to create env-agnostic artifacts.

Comment: I agree on the discussion thing, post getting long

Comment: I created a chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50698/maven-profiles to continue this discussion if needed.