# Filtering in maven-war-plugin does not exclude directory

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

This is a followup of my yesterday question [Conditionally exclude some resources in maven from war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082104/conditionally-exclude-some-resources-in-maven-from-war). I was able to rearrange both development and production wars but filtering copies a directory `properties` to the war though it shall be excluded according to [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html). I could use `packagingExcludes` option, but I wonder why `excludes` does not work. Thank you for explanation.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>dev</classifier>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-dev</webappDirectory>
        <filters>
            <filter>${project.basedir}/configurations/properties/config_dev.prop</filter>
        </filters>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>configurations</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>package-prod</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>prod</classifier>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-prod</webappDirectory>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/*.jks,WEB-INF/classes/acquirer.properties</packagingExcludes>
                <filters>
                    <filter>${project.basedir}/configurations/properties/config_prod.prop</filter>
                </filters>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>configurations</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exclusions for resources are on file base, i.e. they ignore folders. This is because of potential filtering done for webResources.

So, the globs in `excludes` are applied to all files in the directory, any **file** matching an exclude glob is excluded.

However, you only excluded a directory.

Change to `**/properties/*` or `**/properties/**` and it will work.

Comment: It works. Maven has a bug in their documentation. I copied this element from their sample.

Comment: Indeed the docs have a bug. I have been trying the wrong problem for good 6 hours. I wish I googled the right thing earlier. I suppose it is the case even for the "include"? @blackbuild