# how to exclude files based on the if-else condition in pom.xml apache maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I want to exclude some files based on the if-else condition in pom.xml file any one of you guys can you assist me 
here is my pom.xml plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<configuration>
    <warSourceExcludes>**extensions/securelistener.config,
    **extensions/https-reencrypt.config,
    **extensions/https-lbsecuritygroup.config,
    **extensions/https-backendsecurity.config,
    **extensions/99_https-instance.config,
    **ebextensions/httpd/conf/**,
    **ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
    </warSourceExcludes>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: With classifier ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082104/conditionally-exclude-some-resources-in-maven-from-war

Comment: no i want to exclude some files based on if-else condition!!!

Comment: There is no such thing in native Maven. But you can use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) as well. If you really need if-else statements, have a look on [Maven AntRun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).